# htaccess redirect is appending a query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

If i go to rocketroofing.us/rocket, it redirects me to rocketroofing.us/rochester-minnesota-roofing-contractor?/rocket. Why is it appending that query string and how can i fix it?

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    # redirect from the old controller names to the new ones to try and help our SEO.
    #redirect 301 / http://rocketroofing.us/rochester-minnesota-roofing-contractor
    redirect 301 /rocket http://rocketroofing.us/rochester-minnesota-roofing-contractor
    redirect 301 /about http://rocketroofing.us/about-rochester-rocket-roofing
    redirect 301 /faq http://rocketroofing.us/frequently-asked-questions
    redirect 301 /contact http://rocketroofing.us/contact-minnesota-roofing-company

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "rocket";
$route['404_override'] = '';
// used to try and increase my SEO
$route['rochester-minnesota-roofing-contractor'] = 'rocket';
$route['about-rochester-rocket-roofing'] = 'about';
$route['frequently-asked-questions'] = 'faq';
$route['contact-minnesota-roofing-company'] = 'contact';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting the behavior here:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The `$1` is a backreference to whatever you matched in the regular expression with `.*`.

That query string will be used unless you define your own like this:

```
redirect 301 /rocket http://rocketroofing.us/rochester-minnesota-roofing-contractor?
```

Note the trailing question mark.  Documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query
>   string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string
>   to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the
>   query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old
>   query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

Comment: In using your suggestion, the question mark is in the redirected url. Is there a way to not have the question mark in the redirected url?

Comment: @Catfish - You specify it in the configuration file, but it is still not supposed to be part of the redirected URL.  Why do you think it is?  Do you have any code that can detect it?

Comment: Oh so all i needed to do was remove the question mark from the `RewriteRule`? Geeze why didn't ya say so!

Comment: The htaccess file i'm using is one that is posted on the CI website for removing the index.php from the url. Not sure how familiar with CI you are, but thanks for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Catfish - You are welcome.  I thought you might be needing the parameter in some other ones of the redirected URLs or something, so I thought it safer to explain the whole pipeline.